# SwiftUI buttons change text size at appear

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar

[image]

As can be seen in the GIF, the "Done" button text becomes larger as soon as the sheet is completely open. This not only happens in this view, but also in others which use systemimages instead of text. Does anyone know a solution to the problem or do I do something wrong? I'm still relive new with Swift.

```
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            ...
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showSheet = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done")
                        .bold()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set font type to avoid this size changing behaviour.

```
Button(action: {
   self.showSheet = false
}) {
   Text("Done")
        .font(.headline)
        .bold()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. The text is still changing its size. Is that a known bug in SwiftUI 3 / iOS 15 maybe?

Comment: I found out that the size of the text does not change if the text size in the iOS settings are set to at least the middle dot of the slider (under Display & Brightness > Text size). Everything smaller changes the size of the text. Looks like an iOS bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is now solved in iOS 16 beta. (Both public and developer beta)