# SwiftUI toolbar text size changes on appear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194730/swiftui-buttons-change-text-size-at-appear)

[image: Gif]

I am trying to make an app based on Notes app.

I set my iPhone text size to the smallest, and when the view changes, the texts on new view's toolbar gets bigger.

Code :

```
.toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    parentList.starred.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Label("Toggle Favorite", systemImage: parentList.starred ? "star.fill" : "star")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        .foregroundColor(parentList.starred ? .yellow : .gray)
                }
                
                Button(action: editList) {
                    Label("Edit List", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
                }
                
                EditButton()
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Spacer()
        }
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .status) {
            if parentList.childvocabularies!.count == nil {
                Text("")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            else if parentList.childvocabularies!.count == 1{
                Text("\(parentList.childvocabularies!.count) Vocabulary")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
            } else {
                Text("\(parentList.childvocabularies!.count) Vocabularies")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
        }
        
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is solved in iOS 16 beta.

Answer (score 0):

While this introduces other issues (like changing left padding), you can try:

```
Text("ACCOUNT")
    .font(.boldFont(size: 14))
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

Minimum scale factor prevents the font size from increasing and fixed size prevents the text from being truncated. Bold font is our custom extension getting our custom font in bold.